# What does the ? signify in the googlemaps api description (method signature)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This may sound to be a stupid question but I cannot figure out what the "?" signify in the google maps api documentation. For example:

On methods on infowindow, the open() method is described as:

```
 open(map?:Map|StreetViewPanorama, anchor?:MVCObject)
```

Or

```
 Polyline(opts?:PolylineOptions)
```

What does the "?" signify?  I know of ? in regular expressions, typically representing a single character. I don't think thats what this is.

Sorry for asking this basic, hopefully not a very stupid, question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` indicates an optional parameter to the call.

Comment: Thanks. Is that some kind of a standard or just something   specific to the Google Maps API documentation?

Comment: I've seen it used elsewhere. Thought it was documented or discussed somewhere at some point, but can't find the reference in the time available.